# how to let bosh errand execute on existed vms

Tags: bosh-deployer

All, 
I have an issue, how to let bosj errand on existed vms,
I have a vm deployed a mongodb, and i want to run some errand command in the vm, but i don't know how? 
Do any one know this?

Director task 2121

Task 2121 done

```
+---------+---------+---------+--------------+
| VM      | State   | VM Type | IPs          |
+---------+---------+---------+--------------+
| app-p/0 | stopped | app     | 10.62.90.171 |
+---------+---------+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Errands in bosh don't run on existing VMs, bosh brings up new VMs for them.

Comment: that is a bad news to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to run an errand:

```
bosh run errand ERRAND_NAME [--download-logs] [--logs-dir DESTINATION_DIRECTORY]
```

ref: http://bosh.io/docs/sysadmin-commands.html#errand

Assuming you have already marked the deployment job 'lifecycle' as 'errand' in your manifest

ref: Jobs Block section of http://bosh.io/docs/deployment-manifest.html

Like Ben Moss mentioned in his comment, a new VM is created for running an errand job. The errand VM does not stay around after the errand completes. Errand is a short lived job and can be run multiple times

Comment: This is a fairly common ask, and it's a shame that `errands` don't support running an errand on a particular set of VMs. For now we often scrape by with a `bosh ssh` executing `bash files` we store in our release.